# Parameter passing to stored procedure in an efficient way

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, parameter-passing

Hi what is the efficient way to pass parameters to stored procedure in SQL Server?

Actually my parameter value contains some thing like

`@empids = '1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9'`

some thing like this up to 1000

So I tried to pass 1000 comma-separated values to a single parameter and it is working fine.

But is there any other best solutions than this?

Thank you

Comment: asked hundreds of times already on SO....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Sql Server 2008 you can use a [Table-Valued Parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510489.aspx)

Other than that, yes, that is the accepted solution.

You can also have a look at the [XML data type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187339.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can pass parameter using xml also

like as

```
string CustomerIdXML ="<NewDataSet><Table1><Id>56</Id></Table1><Table1><Id>57</Id></Table1></NewDataSet>";

SqlParameter[] _param = new SqlParameter[1];
_param[0] = new SqlParameter("@XDoc", CustomerIdXML);

SqlDataAccess.ExecuteNonQuery(SqlDataAccess.ConnectionString, CommandType.StoredProcedure, "sp1", _param);
```

You can retrive id in sp using followin way

```
CREATE PROC [dbo].[sp1]        
  @xDoc NTEXT   
As       

DECLARE @docHandle INT          

EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @docHandle OUTPUT, @xDoc          
BEGIN TRANSACTION          

UPDATE Tbl SET ISDelete = 1 WHERE Id IN (SELECT Id FROM OPENXML(@docHandle, '/NewDataSet/Table1', 3) WITH (Id BIGINT))  

IF @@ERROR <> 0         
    BEGIN         
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION        
        RETURN @@ERROR       
    END          
COMMIT TRANSACTION          

EXEC sp_xml_removedocument @docHandle          
RETURN 1
```

Hopw you like this way

Comment: XML is great but in this case try to keep things simple. Otherwise you might end up with two problems.